# Combinatorial game problem

Tags: combinatorics

This problem comes from an Australian TST:

Players A and B take turns in putting numbers 1 to 64 into an 8x8 chessboard with player A going first. After all 64 numbers are placed, the smallest numbers in each column are circled. Let S be the sum of all circled numbers.

i) can player A play so that S always even

ii) can they force odd S?

I’ve tried proving that player A can win, since them going first can't possibly hurt their chances of winning. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your working? It's hard to know how to help you with it unless we see it; otherwise we'll just be doing it from scratch

Comment: Why is it that "going first cant possibly hurt his chances of winning"? If I understand your rules, player A loses on the $1\times1$ board and on the $2\times2$ board. Why is the $8\times8$ board different?

Answer (score 1):

It's not at all clear that moving first wouldn't hurt. First-mover advantage doesn't exist in every game! A common kind of $2$nd player strategy that might be worth checking is a strategy where the $2$nd player responds to the $1$st player's move independent of previous moves in a game (somewhat like a "mirroring" strategy).

Here's a hint to get you started: Let's say that Player $2$ pairs up the numbers from $1$ to $64$ in a certain manner and tries the following strategy: whenever Player $1$ plays a number in a certain column, Player $2$ responds by playing the other number of the corresponding pair in the same column. Convince yourself why this is always possible. Is there a way to pair the numbers strategically to win either/both game(s)?